# Spring @Autowired - what is happening in the background

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Excuse me if this is has already been discussed, I could not find a satisfying answer.

I do not understand whats happening when i create a bean in Springframework and @Autowired it to a field in another bean. I understand the result of @Autowired and other annotations but i do not know how its done by Spring.

```
class Sample1{
    //
}

class Sample2{
@Autowired
Sample1 sample1Bean;
}

<bean id="sample1Bean" class="...Sample1"/>
<bean id="sample2Bean" class="...Sample2"/>
```

My question is how does spring set the field sample1Bean in Sample2? i am not expecting a complete explanation, but a direction where i have to look would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Autowired`, `@Inject` annotations are resolved by a [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) - specifically [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). This bean post processor intercepts the creation(for cases where @Autowired is on constructors) of beans, setting of property on the beans to ensure that all the autowired fields are appropriately set.

Answer (score 2):

Im no expert in Spring but I will answer what I know. When a spring powered web application starts up, Spring framework goes through bean instantiation process in the application context. While creating beans Spring checks the required dependencies for a given bean. It looks up a matching bean based on the required type of bean and autowires it when `@Autowired` annotation is specified.

In the above example, Spring will go through application context and create a bean(object) of type `Sample1`. When it will construct bean `Sample2` it sees `@Autowired`annotation and will look for instantiated bean of type `Sample1`. When it finds bean of type `Sample1` it will inject that bean on `Sample2` and finish creating `Sample2`. This is called dependency injection and is one of the very popular features of Spring framework.

Hope this helps.